Google Maps search bar not working in React Native with GooglePlacesAutocomplete
I am working on a React Native project where I have integrated a Google Map with a cursor, and everything works fine. I added a GooglePlacesAutocomplete component to provide a search bar for the user to search for locations. However, the search bar does not work. When I type something into it, nothing appears.
Additionally, I created a function handleLocationSelectto link the GooglePlacesAutocomplete with the map cursor so that when the user searches for something, the cursor automatically moves to the location's latitude and longitude. I would like to know if this function is implemented correctly.
const Location= () => {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState('');
  const [markerCoordinates, setMarkerCoordinates] = useState({ latitude: 24.4539, longitude: 54.3773 });
  const API_KEY = '893d1465300549d88490773eddb7f9f2';
  const GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyAnmKvj5E4qVZJTGtVJtMU4B2P3op8Ce0o';

  const handleMapPress = async (event) => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
    setMarkerCoordinates({ latitude, longitude });

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${latitude}+${longitude}&key=${API_KEY}`
      );
      const components = response.data.results[0].components;
      const location =
        components.town ||
        components.city ||
        components.village ||
        components.hamlet ||
        components.locality ||
        components.country;

      if (location) {
        setSelectedLocation(location);
      } else {
        setSelectedLocation('Unknown location');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching location data: ', error);
    }
  };

  const handleLocationSelect = (data, details = null) => {
    const { lat, lng } = details.geometry.location;
    setMarkerCoordinates({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng });
    setSelectedLocation(details.name);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="transparent"
        barStyle="dark-content"
        translucent={true}
      />

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.form}>
        <View style={styles.head}>
          <BackArrow />
          <Text style={styles.title}>Location</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ width: '90%' }}>
          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Search'
            fetchDetails={true}
            onPress={handleLocationSelect}
            query={{
              key: GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY,
              language: 'en',
            }}
            styles={{
              container: { width: '100%', zIndex: 1 },
              textInput: {
                height: 51,
                borderRadius: 15,
                color: Colors.SmokeBlue,
                fontSize: 13,
                fontFamily: FONTS.PoppinsRegular,
                marginTop: '10%',
                paddingHorizontal: 15,
              },
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <MapView
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 24.4539,
            longitude: 54.3773,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          onPress={handleMapPress}
        >
          {markerCoordinates && (
            <Marker
              coordinate={markerCoordinates}
              title={selectedLocation}
            />
          )}
        </MapView>

        {selectedLocation && (
          <View style={styles.selectedLocationContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.selectedLocationText}>Selected Location: {selectedLocation}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Location;

